# QField: Points aren't straight, they are dirty and blurred

Tags: qgis, qfield

I've made a project in QGIS, imported a new layer with coordinates (points) from a csv-file. Finally I want to find this marks in the area within 10 cm.

In QGIS everything worked fine.

When I made the QField-Package, it works, I can open it in QField.

But the points are displayed not clear. It looks like, they've got a new dirty, blurred background. I already tried everything to lose it. But I haven't found a solution.

[image: in QGis]

[image: in QField]

[image: QField Picture 2]

Does anybody have an idea why this is?

Comment: this looks more like a problem of your background layer than of your point layer. what do you have as background?

Comment: It look like the points are on a raster background as well as a vector layer could you edit your question with yopur QField-Package export setting ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you created (maybe accidentially) a basemap in QFieldSync containing your point layer. Maybe by the use of a MapTheme.

[image]

Edit:
Btw. once there has been a bug, that it created a basemap containing all the layers, leading to your behavior. In case it's that, then you can use a workaround by setting only the maps visible in your project, you want to have on your basemap.